# URL styling for backtick formatted text

Tags: feature-request

When linking to backtick formatted text like so:

[`google`](http://www.google.com)

It's very hard to tell it's a link. I think that links inside the resulting backtick stylings should be made a brighter blue to make this apparent. The usage case for this is escaping a function and linking to the documentation on it.

**Edit**: Example in Chrome on Mac OSX:

---

[image: Example showing the hard to detect formatting]

---

This occurs for me on meta and StackOverflow.

Comment: I'd say this is site specific styling...

Comment: @Cawas It looks like this on Meta and StackOverflow. Not sure if there's a standard way to handle this, but at the very least it would be nice to see it on these two.

Comment: And I agree, just mentioning I think not every SEN site is like this. At very least for sure they don't need to be.

Answer (score 2):

`Google?`

```
<code><u>[Google?](http://google.com)</u></code>
```

Comment: Nice workaround!